# I want my edit route to re-render the page with an update and not actually link to the edit route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have been working on this problem for a while and I'm still not understanding how it works. I am trying to implement a feature to allow users to update existing events in the app. I added in links that say "Edit", and I would like it if upon pressing 'Edit' the form gets filled in with the event's attributes. I have a page that looks like this:

[image]

From here the user should be able to create, update, and delete events.

I can't seem to figure out how the route works for update. (Or maybe I should be using edit?) **Here is what my show partial looks like:**

```
.right-half#FrontDeskEventTable
    %h1 Events
    =render partial: 'form'

    %table.color-table
      -@front_desk_date.front_desk_date_events.each do |t|
        %tr
          - next if t.new_record?
          %td{style: 'padding: 10px;'}= t.subject
          %td= link_to "Edit", admin_front_desk_front_desk_profile_path(@front_desk_date, "#{t.id}"), method: :update
          %td{style: 'padding: 0px 5px 0px 30px;'}= link_to "Delete", admin_front_desk_date_front_desk_date_event_path(@front_desk_date, "#{t.id}"), method: :delete, confirm: "Delete #{t.subject}?"
```

**and in my front_desk_date_events_controller:**

```
def edit
    @front_desk_date_event = @front_desk_date.front_desk_date_events.find(params[:id])

    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'FrontDeskEventTable', partial: 'form', object: @front_desk_date_event
    end
  end
```

**When the user clicks edit it leads to a page admin/front_desk_dates/1/front_desk_date_events/2/edit that looks like:**

```
Element.update("FrontDeskEventTable", "\u003Cform accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/intranet/admin/front_desk_dates/1/front_desk_date_events/2\" class=\"edit_front_desk_date_event, etc, etc
```

If anyone is willing to read this whole post and help I will be very grateful.

Comment: Please add exact error message and your `routes.rb`.

Comment: - next if t.new_record?
why are you doing that?

Comment: btw: the update event should not render a template - it should update something and then redirect back to show/edit action

Comment: link_to "edit", edit_admin_bla_path(object)

no need to specify the action

Comment: Without the -next if t.new_record? the table shows an extra event that is blank. I am looking into your other advice. Thanks

Comment: sorry, theres no real help in here if you are doing it the "non-rails-way". in rails your controller is showing an object, edit renders the form and update is updating and then redirecting. your controller is wrong (and by that especially your routes). there is no wonder, that you get routing-errors since you are using the routes in a totally wrong wayn.

if you want to show a form to create a new object, or load data into it with a singleclick and then update it, you watch out for in-place editing gems or write your own stuff with lots of javascript and ajax.

Comment: Okay, good to know and thanks for all the info, I think I may just make a separate partial for editing the event. Thanks again!

Comment: no, there is no need for a second partial. it is possible to do it the way you do. but not with those controllers. you really need to start and write a standard basic controller. then you might understand, how those routes are working

Answer (score 0):

Perform `rake routes` in a terminal. You should see something along the lines of `edit_admin_front_desk_front_desk_profile`, so you'll want to use `edit_admin_front_desk_front_desk_profile_path(@front_desk_date)` in the `link_to` helper.